# How to change Android VideoView content color when data isn't ready

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player, android-videoview

I'm working on a video player app, and I'm using a VideoView to show the videos. The videos are obtained from a url like so

```
videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
videoView.start();
```

When there's no internet connection, the videoView just looks all black on the screen. I would like to change this default black screen to another image.

Any tips on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe the simplest way for you is to put your VideoView into some parent layout and set background resource for that container

Answer (score 1):

Now when your video is playing hide the placeholder and when your network is off hide the videoview